# Can the Polymorph spell turn a character into a dragon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, dragons

This first sentence in the [*polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell description says (emphasis mine):

> This spell transforms a creature with at least 1 hit point that you can see within range into a **new form**.

I have heard that *polymorph* only turns into a "beast", but one of my players pointed out the "new form" part, claiming that a level 7 wizard could turn a level 6 paladin into a [young white dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/young-white-dragon) (challenge rating 6).

This doesn't sound right to me, because I think it's only beasts... Maybe it's a druid thing?

Does "new form" in the *polymorph* spell description mean "any creature or monster"? Or does it just mean "any beast"?

Comment: Worth noting: you have adequate answers saying that this isn't possible at 7th level, but pulling something like this was much easier to do in 3rd edition. You having heard that is probably people talking about previous editions, or them not realizing that Polymorph has changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the book suggest polymorphing into a giant? Can polymorph do that?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104260/why-does-the-book-suggest-polymorphing-into-a-giant-can-polymorph-do-that)

Comment: While it may be good to have a single question on this topic, it probably shouldn't be the one stuffed half full of spoilers about a very specific adventure module. The whole "not all polymorphing is the spell" thing could be covered in a new canonical question.

Answer (score 40):

#### Polymorph (4th level) is limited in what it can turn things into.

From the spell text (second paragraph):

> The new form can be **any beast** whose challenge rating is equal to or
> less than the target’s (or the target’s level, if it doesn’t have a
> challenge rating).

A beast is a particular creature type.  The creature *type* is listed in the stat block of a creature.   Compare [adult red dragon](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/DMBasicRulesV05.pdf#page=8) (dragon) with [allosaurus](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/DMBasicRulesV05.pdf#page=9)(beast).

> Beasts are nonhumanoid creatures that are a natural part of the fantasy ecology. Some of them have magical powers, but most are unintelligent and lack any society or language. Beasts include all varieties of ordinary animals, dinosaurs, and giant versions of animals.  ([Basic Rules, p. 110](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=110)).

[Other types include fiend, fey, dragon, aberration, celestial, construct, monstrosity, ooze, and humanoid.](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/DMBasicRulesV05.pdf#page=2)  Unless the creature form chosen is a beast (allosaurus, brown bear, etc) the 4th level *polymorph* spell won't turn the PC into a dragon.  As far as the game is concerned, a dragon is not a beast; a dragon is its own *type* of creature.

> **Dragons** are large reptilian creatures of ancient origin and tremendous
> power. True dragons, including the good metallic dragons and the evil
> chromatic dragons, are highly intelligent and have innate magic. Also
> in this category are creatures distantly related to true dragons, but
> less powerful, less intelligent, and less magical, such as wyverns and
> pseudodragons. ([Basic Rules, p. 110](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=110)).

#### The 9th level spell, True Polymorph, has no such restriction.

> **Creature into Creature**. If you turn a creature into another kind of creature, **the new form can be any kind you choose** whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target’s (or its level, if the target doesn’t have a challenge rating).

Your friend may be confusing the two spells, or may not see the distinction between the two creature types.  On a humorous note, @NathanS suggests that the most powerful choices for *polymorph* (4th level) are Godzilla (T-Rex, CR 8, beast) or King Kong (Giant Ape, CR 7, beast). How does the character, or the player, feel about being polymorphed into one of those magnificent beasts?  The PC would need to be level 8 or 7 (respectively) for that to work.

---

Over four years later ... as we have adventured more in Tier 2 and 3 games, it's not uncommon for our wizard to turn my level 7+ PC into a Giant Ape. Good speed, not great AC, lots of HP, throwing rocks is a nice attack, or get in close and two hard hitting punch attacks (non magical) ... or the grapple.  Fun change of pace to be King Kong for a little while.   The reason I prefer that to the T-Rex is that the Giant Ape's INT score is 7.  Easier to role play/rationalize than a 2 INT giant lizard who is usually hungry ...

Comment: "chosen beast" does that make it a beast then? or still anything?

Comment: so a wizard turns a paladin into a dragon with 4th level polymorph, even if the dragon is of the same challenge rating, wouldn't work, correct?

Comment: @Youjay No, he doesn't, since a dragon is not a beast type, it is a dragon type.

Comment: @Youjay He can turn the paladin into a dinosaur. Just saying...

Comment: @Youjay Page 6 of Monster Manual defines "beasts" and discusses how these creature types are relevant to spells, notably: "Certain spells…interact in special ways with creatures of a particular type." So when you see "beast" in a spell definition, it's referring to the term defined on page 6.

Comment: I DM'd a party whose favorite strategy for killing dragons was to polymorph the raging barbarian into King Kong, grapple the dragon (+9 Athletics vs about +5 STR) and hold it in a Wall of Fire

Comment: @DaleM Good times.  While not a rule, it seems that the more common [rules interpretation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136142/23547) is that the barbarian's rage would not be in effect while polymorphed.  If you, as DM, did permit it, though, the grapple should have been +9 Athletics _with advantage_.

Answer (score 27):

### *Polymorph* can't turn creatures into dragons, only beasts

The [*polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell's description says "new form" at first, but then later specifies that the new form must be a beast (emphasis mine):

> This spell transforms a creature with at least 1 hit point that you can see within range into a new form. [...] **The new form can be any beast** whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target's (or the target's level, if it doesn't have a challenge rating).

When the game says "beast", it is talking about a specifically defined game term. Every creature in D&D 5e has a [type](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Type), and beast is one of those types. You can find a creature's type at the top of its statblock, just under the creature name, listed after its size (e.g. "Medium beast").

If the statblock for a creature says "beast" as its type, then it is applicable for the *polymorph* spell to turn a creature into that form. Anything else (dragon, fiend, aberration, fey, etc.) is not allowed.

## A dragon is not a beast

If you look at an [adult red dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/adult-red-dragon)'s statblock, it says: "dragon". Since it does not say "beast", it is not an applicable form for *polymorph*.

If you look at the statblock of a [cat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/cat) or a [black bear](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/black-bear) it says "beast", so it would be allowed.

## Common points of confusion

Don't confuse the spell [*polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) with the spell [*true polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph), because *true polymorph* has no such creature type restrictions on its transformation. It is also a 9th-level spell, so your wizard will not be casting it any time soon.

Druids have an ability somewhat similar to *polymorph* called [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#WildShape-167). However, like *polymorph*, it can only be used to transform into beasts. There are other differences between the spell and the druid feature as well, but those are unimportant for this question as long as you understand they are separate things.

Comment: However, dinosaurs are perfectly valid targets. Turning party members into T-rexes is always good times.

Comment: @guildsbounty Godzilla and King Kong, the best two options for Polymorph!

Comment: Consider keeping a wizard in t rex's mouth for breath attacks